# Clarification on the Poisson distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

Given that an event occurs at some rate $\lambda$ per unit time, I know that the probability that n such events occur in unit time is given by the Poisson distribution.

$P(n) = e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}$

However, let's say I measure the time intervals at which the next event occurs. I obtain a histogram since the events happen randomly and this is a PDF because each event occurs at some time between $t=0$ and $t=\infty$. What distribution does this follow? I thought earlier, that it was

$P(t) = \lambda t e^{-\lambda t}$

but this is incorrect. Integrating this from $t=0$ to $t=\infty$ yields $\frac{1}{\lambda}$. I would guess then that

$P(t) = \lambda^2 t e^{-\lambda t}$ but the expectation value of this is $\frac{2}{\lambda}$, which doesn't make sense. If events occur at a rate $\lambda$, the expected time of each event should be $\frac{1}{\lambda}$.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time $T$ until the next event has continuous distribution, with density function $f_T(t)=\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$ for $t\gt 0$, and $f_T(t)=0$ elsewhere.

The distribution of $T$ is called the *exponential distribution* with parameter $\lambda$.

The expectation $E(T)$ (mean) of $T$ is given by $E(T)=\int_0^\infty t\lambda e^{-\lambda t}\,dt$. Integration shows this is $\dfrac{1}{\lambda}$, exactly as you expected.

Added: The following is an informal justification of the result. If the number of events in unit time has Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$, then the number of events in time $\lambda t$ has Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda t$. So the probability the number of events is $0$ is $e^{-\lambda t}\frac{(\lambda t)^0}{0!}$, that is, $e^{-\lambda t}$.

Thus the probability that the waiting time $T$ is $\gt t$ is $e^{-\lambda t}$. Thus the cdf $F_T(t)$, that is, the probability that $T\le t$, is given by $1-e^{-\lambda t}$, for positive $t$.

Differentiation now gives us the density function $f_T(t)$ described above.

Comment: That justification is excellent. Very intuitive, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.